# ¿Donde guardo la base de datos en una aplicacion de escritorio?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion de escritorio en python, la aplicación funciona correctamente. Utilice pyinstaller para generar el .exe, y installforge para generar el instalador.

La base de datos es un archivo de sqlite, este lo guardo en un carpeta dentro de la raíz del proyecto, pero cuando después de instalarlo, el programa requiere permisos de administrador para poder modificar la base de datos.

¿Existe alguna manera de que no me pida dichos permisos?

¿Necesito guardar la base de datos en algún otro lugar?

¿Cuál es la mejor opción para hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Yo te recomendaría no poner la base de datos en la carpeta raíz del proyecto ya que puede afectar el funcionamiento dependiendo de donde lo instale el usuario y en un futuro si quisieras expandir a otros sistemas operativos sería más complicado.

Una buena opción es utilizar el paquete [`platformdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) que soporta multiplataforma y por ejemplo podrías utilizar la carpeta `AppData` en Windows o su equivalente en otros sistemas operativos.

Ejemplo básico de Windows 7 tomado de la página del módulo

```
>>> from platformdirs import *
>>> appname = "SuperApp"
>>> appauthor = "Acme"
>>> user_data_dir(appname, appauthor)
'C:\\Users\\trentm\\AppData\\Local\\Acme\\SuperApp'
>>> user_data_dir(appname, appauthor, roaming=True)
'C:\\Users\\trentm\\AppData\\Roaming\\Acme\\SuperApp'
>>> user_cache_dir(appname, appauthor)
'C:\\Users\\trentm\\AppData\\Local\\Acme\\SuperApp\\Cache'
>>> user_log_dir(appname, appauthor)
'C:\\Users\\trentm\\AppData\\Local\\Acme\\SuperApp\\Logs'
>>> user_documents_dir()
'C:\\Users\\trentm\\Documents'
>>> user_runtime_dir(appname, appauthor)
'C:\\Users\\trentm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Acme\\SuperApp'
```

Como puedes ver, hay varias funciones para generar carpetas en diferentes ubicaciones y que puedan trabajar de forma segura con tu aplicación.